# How do I unmarshal json to a []Person?

Tags: go

I am trying to dynamically set a field that is of type interface{}. In all of the cases below the json unmarshals into the correct structure but in the "problem" case the json unmarshals to []interface{}. For that case I am expecting []Person. Why do I get the wrong type for "problem"?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Employees struct {
    Indicator string      `json:"indicator"`
    Items     interface{} `json:"items"`
}

type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    simple()
    easy()
    moreDifficult()
    problem()
}

var j = []byte(`{"name": "bob"}`)
var jj = []byte(`[{"name": "bob"}, {"name": "jim"}, {"name": "fred"}]`)


func simple() {
    p := Person{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(j, &p); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("easy:", p, reflect.TypeOf(p))
}

func easy() {
    p := []Person{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jj, &p); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("easy:", p, reflect.TypeOf(p))
}

func moreDifficult() {
    var j = []byte(`{"indicator": "more difficult"}`)

    e := Employees{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(j, &e); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("moreDifficult", e.Items, reflect.TypeOf(e.Items))
}

func problem() {
    var j = []byte(`{"indicator:": "problem"}`)

    e := Employees{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(j, &e); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("problem:", e.Items, reflect.TypeOf(e.Items)) // why not []Person???
}


func (e *Employees) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type alias Employees

    a := &alias{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &a); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    e.Indicator = a.Indicator

    var k = jj

    if e.Indicator == "more difficult" {
        k = j
        e.Items = &Person{}
    } else {
        e.Items = []Person{}
    }

    return json.Unmarshal(k, &e.Items)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xQvjMyLTk5i

Comment: `json.Unmarshal(k, &e.Items)` You're passing a pointer to an interface i.e. `*interface{}`, you should not do that, you should pass a pointer to a concrete type e.g. `*[]Person`.

Comment: ... https://play.golang.org/p/HeLMoMvNtU7

Comment: Because Go is statically type. You unmarshal into interface{}, you get interface{}.

Comment: @mkopriva can you please post as an answer? thansk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the interface's underlying value is not a pointer:

```
e.Items = []Person{}
```

While it's true that you're passing a pointer to the interface itself:

```
json.Unmarshal(k, &e.Items)
```

That does not fix the problem of the underlying value being a non-pointer.

```
var a interface{} = &T{}

var b interface{} = T{}
b = &b
```

The types of `a` and `b` are different and will be handled differently by the unmarshaler, in `b`'s case the unmarshaler will elect to replace the pointed-to value with a `map[string]interface{}`.

So to fix your immediate problem you can do something like this:

```
if e.Indicator == "more difficult" {
    k = j
    e.Items = &Person{}
} else {
    e.Items = &[]Person{}
}

return json.Unmarshal(k, e.Items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem has absolutely nothing to do with JSON unmarshaling.

You define `Items` as type `interface{}`, so obviously, when you inspect it, it will be of type `interface{}`. If you want it to be of type `[]Person`, simply define it as such:

```
type Employees struct {
    Indicator string   `json:"indicator"`
    Items     []Person `json:"items"`
}
```

Once you've done that, your test case will yield the expected results. But your `Items` will still be empty, as your input JSON doesn't have the `items` field.

Comment: redefining it is not an option

Comment: Then what you're trying to do is impossible.